# Is possible to do "data control flow" during class initialization in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop

In the code below i tried to insert the End statement inside the if..then block to check if temperature value passed to the constructor is between -20 and +50 degrees, and eventually END the program execution if the requirement is not met. Visual Studio tells that the "End statement cannot be used in class library projects". What is the good practice/ approach to check the correctness of parameters passed to a class constructor? (I have read that exceptions should not be used to perform data control flow since exceptions should be used to address "unexpected behaviors" and in this case, i should expect that the user might try to insert a value outside the allowable range for this class to be meaningful).

Thank you

```
Public Class WaterGlycoleMixture
     Implements ICoolingFluid

     Private _temperature As Double
     Private _glycolePercentage As Double

     Public Sub New(temperature As Double, glycolePercentage As Double)

          If -20 < temperature < 50 Then
               MessageBox.Show("Error: Temperature Range must be between -20 e +50°C")
                End
          End If

          _temperature = temperature
          _glycolePercentage = glycolePercentage
     End Sub


    'Some more methods and properties here




End Class
```

Comment: That's just not valid syntax. There is no such thing as an `End` statement. You end an `If` block, or  `While` loop, or `Class` or `Namespace`, etc. But all of those must be in the proper order ( you can't end a while loop with an if block inside before you end the if block, for example), and you _never_ have `End` on a line by itself in VB.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn : Actually you can, see: [`End` Statement | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/end-statement) it'd basically equivalent to `Environment.Exit(0)`.

Comment: Yes: Read up on exception handling. They are entirely appropriate here.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn As the saying goes, you have probably forgotten more of VB.NET than some other people will ever learn. ;-)

Comment: @Visual Vincent: In fact what i am trying to do is to suspend all the program if the values passed are not acceptable. Since the validation functions are actually inside the class, which is the best strategy/good practice to perform a data control flow during class initialization and eventually make the program to react to some bad values?

Comment: _"I have read that exceptions should not be used to perform data control flow since exceptions should be used to address 'unexpected behaviors'"_ - Entering invalid data counts as unexpected behaviour. Your class/code was not designed to work with such data, ergo it is not expected to be supplied with it. Use exceptions to inform the programmer/user that he/she has made a mistake, then it's up to whoever uses your library to gracefully catch the exception and display the error message to the user (or terminate the application, depending on the case).

Comment: _"In fact what i am trying to do is to suspend all the program if the values passed are not acceptable"_ - Why do you need to close the entire application? Why isn't the user allowed to correct his/her mistake? || _"Since the validation functions are actually inside the class, which is the best strategy/good practice to perform a data control flow during class initialization and eventually make the program to react to some bad values?"_ - (explained in my comment above)

Comment: Also, as a side note statements like this doesn't work: `If -20 < temperature < 50 Then`. The first part: `-20 < temperature` will result in either `True` or `False`, meaning the second part will be evaluated as `(True or False) < 50`, which will always be true. You need to separate it into two checks. And since your message says that the temperature should be _between_ -20 and +50, you also need to change the operators to check whether it's actually _outside_ this range: `If temperature < -20 OrElse temperature > 50 Then`.

Comment: @Visual Vincent: very thank you for all your explanations.

Answer (score 3):

You absolutely can throw an exception if you are passed a bad argument.  The .NET Framework defines a stock exception class, [ArgumentException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentexception?view=netframework-4.7.2),  for just this reason.

This is particularly true in the case of a Library.  It should be up to the calling code to handle the exception in the manner that is appropriate.  If it is a GUI app, then it can show a message to the user.  If it is a Windows Service, then logging might be more appropriate.  The library should not make assumptions.

Comment: Thank you i was not aware about the ArgumentException. I am very new to programming.